# Need Open CV algorithms book?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, opencv

HI guys,
Currently I am developing an image processing library for android, I need a book/pdf doc which contains all algorithms implemented in open Cv. 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an O'Reilly book by two of the major authors of OpenCV: [Learning OpenCV: Computer Vision with the OpenCV Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) by Bradski and Kaehler.

You should note that it is based on OpenCV 1.0, not the more recent 2.2.

Nonetheless, to understand algorithms it will likely be useful. For most of the higher-level algorithms like corner detection, for example, the book contains a mathematical descriptions of the implementation. Also, the authors do a decent job of providing references to academic journal articles, so even if their own description of the implementation is lacking, you will be able to use the references as a starting point.